# Cannot open anaconda jupyter nb in private mode

Tags: google-chrome, jupyter-notebook, anaconda3

This is strange but i always run Anaconda Jupyter notebook in private mode with Chrome, i don't know what's happened but now when i run Jupyter notebook on anaconda it always open a normal Chrome window. How i can come back to previous mode? I mean everything worked fine until i opened a Jupyter notebook while simultaneously i was changing desktop on my Mac, so Anaconda opened the windows not in Incognito mode (i had already opened a working incognito mode session) but a classic one.

I tried to reinstall anaconda but nothing changed, maybe i think i need to change some config but i really don't know where i have to start. I just would like to open Jupyter in a Chrome private mode.

I'm on MacOS.

Thanks in advance